# detecting a pallet in RGB color image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an RGB image using kinect and I want to detect the pallet size and pallet color in the RGB color data using opencv. 
[image]

Comment: are those pallets identically normed ones or could there be different pallet types in different images? Is the camera position and zoom/tilt/etc. fixed or can it vary? In your sample image, do you intend to detect only the central pallet or even the partially visible pallets at image top?

Comment: yes they are normed ones, the camera position and zoom/tilt is aready fixed. I want to detect only the central pallet

Comment: will those pallets always appear on or close to the ground? Or can they appear on the fork-lift at positions "far" away from the ground (can the z-axis position be limited to some range?)? Can the pallet appear tilted (in height axis)?

Comment: they are close to the ground. no the zaxis is not limited to some range. yes it can appear titled in the height axis a little bit

Comment: Ok. The reason why I ask is that a calibrated scene (ground plane) will help very much here, I guess. You could then try to detect rectangular shapes of a known 3D size, which is limited to quite few degrees of freedom if the z-tilt is small enough (just ignore it). From lifted pallets there is some uncertainty/ambiguity of projected object size, but I guess it would work.
But all in all, this approach would be too complex for a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: With a calibrated scene you could however warp the image to get a "bird'S eye" view of the scene which makes simpler approaches easier because it reduces perspective distortions and you can work with additional assumptions.

Comment: @Micka can you answer with a pseudo code please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115391/discussion-between-andre-and-micka).